# Could not initialize GTK! Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set? on Debian WSL

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gtkwave

I'm trying to use a file **"testar.sh"** to test GHDL and GTKWave installation on Debian, that's the command I should use: `chmod +x testar.sh; ./testar.sh`, then this is what its shown

> Could not initialize GTK!  Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set?
> Usage: gtkwave [OPTION]... [DUMPFILE] [SAVEFILE] [RCFILE]

and a list of commands

Comment: Without anymore information is DISPLAY set and has the X Server been started? :Local or remote access?  Doesn't seem like a programming question, better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, when I tried to run `gtkwave` in windows subsystem for linux (WSL) with ubuntu distribution. The error is due to not having a X server for windows.

My solution was to download [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/). Then, with Xming running in the background, run `export DISPLAY=:0` and you should be able to run your commands that require an X server.

See more info [here](https://www.pcworld.com/article/420529/windows-10s-bash-shell-can-run-graphical-linux-applications-with-this-trick.html)